# Mapping rest model to domain model in Android

Tags: android, domain-driven-design, retrofit

I want to keep my domain model and rest model separate so that I don't have to worry about changing the domain model when rest API changes. Also, I get to work with UI-friendly format by converting rest model to domain model.

I use retrofit to consume Restful web service. In onResponse(), I am mapping the rest model into domain model. I hate instantiating bunch of objects on the main thread. What are some clean ways to map not on main thread?

```
String username = "test";
Call<User> call = apiService.getUser(username);
call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
        int statusCode = response.code();
        User user = response.body();  
        // Want to convert rest model to domain model for my use
        Account account = AccountMapper.map(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
        // Log error here since request failed
    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I return value from function onResponse of Retrofit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34184088/how-can-i-return-value-from-function-onresponse-of-retrofit)

Comment: you can look here to have idea: https://proandroiddev.com/the-real-repository-pattern-in-android-efba8662b754

Answer (score 0):

Generally you want a converter. The converter's job is to interpret from the external Api to your domain context/models. Converters can be implemented as "Factories". You pass the factory method the right parameters and it'll return to you something that your domain understands/can use.

Now, when you say "not instantiating on the main thread": It sounds like you have answered your own question because that sounds like you are suggesting concurrency through threads. Unless you concurrently spin up a new thread, you can move the code around but you'll always be on the "main" thread.

Answer (score -1):

after you get the response just call map{ someMapper().map(from, to)}

here would be the general interface for all your mappers:

```
interface Mapper<FROM, TO> {
fun map(model: FROM): TO
```

}