# How to return value using Async Retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, asynchronous, retrofit2

I am new with retrofit, i have a function with Async Retrofit, with purpose like this example

```
public boolean bookmark(){
   boolean result = false;

   Call<Response> call = service.bookmark(token, request);
   call.enqueue(new Callback<Response>() {

      @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Response> call, retrofit2.Response<Response> response) {
            result = true;
      }
      @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Response call, Throwable t) {

      }
   });

   return result;
}
```

but i dont know how to return that value.

Comment: obviously, you cannot unless you will block `bookmark()` before return for `onResponse` of the callback to get called (with some semaphore/othere synchronization object) ... which obviously would take off all async call advantages

Comment: `I am new with retrofit` and that should be the reason you to read the documentation in the first place.

Comment: thx @selvin, so do you have another way to get value after i call retrofit?

Comment: yes, start thinking in multiythreading way ... and move the code to callback itself

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use a custom interface. If you pass the interface as parameter to the method "bookmark", you can use it.

try something like:

```
public interface BookmarkCallback{
      void onSuccess(boolean value);
      void onError();
}
```

your method should look like:

```
public void bookmark(final BookmarkCallback callback){
     Call<Response> call = service.bookmark(token, request);
     call.enqueue(new Callback<Response>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Response> call, retrofit2.Response<Response> response) {
             callback.onSuccess(true);
       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(Call<Response call, Throwable t) {
           callback.onError();
       }
});
```

When you call this method, you have to pass one callback instance.

Comment: thx @asanchezyu, how to get get value from callback after call bookmark?

Comment: You have several options:
* The class which calls that method implements that interface. 
    `bookmark(this);`
    ....
* In every method call you can create a new instance of that interface.
    `bookmark(new BookmarkCallback{
        public void onSuccess(boolean value){   
            //You can make here all you want with "Value"  
        }  
        public void onError(){  
        }  
    });`