# How can I return data in method from Retrofit onResponse?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm new with retrofit and I want to make my getData method to return a feature object. What is the easiest way to do that?

DataService.java

```
public class DataService {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private final ApiClient apiClient;

    public DataService() {
        apiClient = new ApiClientFactory().createApiClient();
    }

    public List<Feature> getData(){

        apiClient.getData().enqueue(new Callback<DataResponse>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<DataResponse> call, Response<DataResponse> response) {
                List<Feature> features = response.body().getFeatures();
                Log.d(TAG, "Data successfully downloaded");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<DataResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
            }
        });
        //I need to return features in getData method
    }
}
```

Comment: You're question has already been answered on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34184088/how-can-i-return-value-from-function-onresponse-of-retrofit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I return value from function onResponse of Retrofit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34184088/how-can-i-return-value-from-function-onresponse-of-retrofit)

Comment: call.execute().body()

Comment: @uguboz And block the UI thread? No.

Comment: U re right cricket it must be in an asynctask. So an eventbus may be perfect in callback. Maybe rxjava. What do u think

Comment: @uguboz Extra libraries are not necessary. My answer should be fine

Comment: @cricket_007 You wouldn't block UI if you use AsyncTask with execute() :) But your answer with extracting inner Callback was more elegant I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't `return`, you must "call back".

Extract that inner Callback class to a parameter.

```
public void getData(Callback<DataResponse> callback){
    apiClient.getData().enqueue(callback);
}
```

In your other code

```
// DataService service = ...;

// Define Callback
Callback<DataResponse> responseCallback = new Callback<DataResponse>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<DataResponse> call, Response<DataResponse> response) {
        List<Feature> features = response.body().getFeatures();
        Log.d(TAG, "Data successfully downloaded");

        // Data is returned here
        for (Feature f: features) {
            Log.d("feature", String.valueOf(f)); // for example
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<DataResponse> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
    }
};

// Call it
service.getData(responseCallback);
```

You can also do `service.getData(new Callback<DataResponse>() { ... });`

Comment: Ok, I mostly understand it, but how can I create an Instance of DataService in the same class or transfer responseCallback in other class than DataService and pass it to getData method?

Comment: `responseCallback` is a standalone variable, and you can define it wherever you want the actual data. As far as `DataService`... You should already have that in some Activity or Fragment.

Comment: Ok, that was obvious :) But I have another question - how can I extract downloaded data (features) from getData method?

Comment: Look at my answer. `getData()` is void. You do nothing but call it. Everything you want to get can be done from that `List<Feature> features` that you already got it your question.

Comment: Ok, thank you :) I was a bit confused but I get it now :)