# Null pointer exception

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am trying to use retro fit but onResponse and onFailure are not called. I do not get any exceptions too. I am confused where I am doing it wrong. it would be grateful if you can spot something.

Update - I am getting null pointer exception in the OnResponse method.

Url - https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/

API client

```
public class ApiClient {
    public static final String BASE_URL_TWO = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/";
    public static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    public  static Retrofit getApiClient()
    {
        if(retrofit == null)
        {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL_TWO).
                    addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

ApiInterface

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("/posts")
    Call<List<DemoJSONAPIData>> getDemoData();
}
```

ApiCalls

```
public class ApiCalls implements IApiCalls{
    private ApiInterface apiInterface;
    private List<DemoJSONAPIData> demoJSONAPIDatas;

    @Override
    public List<DemoJSONAPIData> getDemoData() {

        try{
            apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
            Call<List<DemoJSONAPIData>> call = apiInterface.getDemoData();
            call.enqueue(new Callback<List<DemoJSONAPIData>>() {
             //Skips out of try catch, no exception being caught
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<DemoJSONAPIData>> call, Response<List<DemoJSONAPIData>> response) {
                  //UPDATE - I am getting NULL pointer here.
                      demoJSONAPIDatas = response.body();
                Log.d("demoJSONAPIDatas", demoJSONAPIDatas.toString());
                for(DemoJSONAPIData demoJSONAPIData: demoJSONAPIDatas){
                    Log.d("UserId", demoJSONAPIData.getId());
                    Log.d("Title", demoJSONAPIData.getTitle());
                }
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<DemoJSONAPIData>> call, Throwable t) {
            //IS not called
                }
            });
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return demoJSONAPIDatas;
    }
}
```

DemoJSONAPIData

```
public class DemoJSONAPIData {
    @SerializedName("userId")
    private String UserId;
    @SerializedName("id")
    private String Id;
    @SerializedName("title")
    private String Title;
    @SerializedName("body")
    private String Body;

    public String getUserId() {
        return UserId;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return Title;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return Body;
    }
}
```

Using it like this

```
List<DemoJSONAPIData> demoJSONAPIDatas = apiCalls.getDemoData();
```

Please suggest where I am doing it wrong.

Thanks
R

Comment: have you chacked catch block may be your api client null

Comment: they do have values, apiInterface and call are NOT null. it does not go into the catch block it skips it

Answer (score 0):

That's because Call.enqueue is *asynchronous*. It doesn't make the request before returning; it initiates the request in another thread and returns immediately. By the time it returns, `demoJSONAPIDatas` is still null because nothing has happened yet. So this

```
List<DemoJSONAPIData> demoJSONAPIDatas = apiCalls.getDemoData();
```

will not work.

Comment: thank you for your reply. what is the solution for this. can you suggest anything

Comment: Instead of returning a list, take the code that uses the list and put it _inside_ the callback. You can achieve this my passing the callback as an argument of getDemoData.

Comment: Another option would be to change _enqueue_ to _execute_ which is synchronous but Android does not allow this (no network access on main thread).

Comment: I did not quite get that, could you share some code sample please.

Comment: I would, but I'm on a phone. Typing code is painfully tedious.

Comment: I will try it, by any chance if you can do it later at your convenience, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your ApiClient and interface.make below changes.

**Baseurl need to change like below**

```
public class ApiClient {
    public static final String BASE_URL_TWO = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/";
    public static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    public  static Retrofit getApiClient()
    {
        if(retrofit == null)
        {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL_TWO).
                    addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

**get() method will be change aswell**

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("posts")
    Call<List<DemoJSONAPIData>> getDemoData();
}
```

**update**

```
private List<DemoJSONAPIData> demoJSONAPIDatas=new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Hello Deep, yes I figured that out and fixed it. but the problem is when i call List<DemoJSONAPIData> demoJSONAPIDatas = apiCalls.getDemoData(); I do not get any data. I have heard OnResponse runs on a separate thread. Any idea how to get that data in my presenter

Comment: yes you got that right enqueue will run on worker thread because when you are making a request and until the response come your app ui shounf not be stuck so prefer enqueue only and check the request method once i seems no problem in code elsewhere.

Comment: I am not exactly sure how to get this to get function getDemoData() to return data from the worker thread. could you suggest how to do it please.

Comment: As I am trying to print whats coming from it List<DemoJSONAPIData> demoJSONAPIDatas = apiCalls.getDemoData();
        gamesView.showToast(demoJSONAPIDatas.toString()); I am getting the NULL pointer exception. I am now aware that the above operation is on the Main thread and the OnResponse is on Worker thread, and by the time worker threads executes, getDemoData() gets NUll and tries to toast and gets a null pointer exception. What is the way to return data from the worker thread and return data any idea Deep

Comment: i have updated my answer check it,you are assigning the response to a null object because you are not initialize it.

Comment: Hello Deep, even if we initialise it,the list is empty.

Comment: did you check your api there is nothing wrong with android point.

Comment: I think this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42636247/how-can-i-return-data-in-method-from-retrofit-onresponse will give you an idea what I am talking about