# mLoggedInUser always null?

Tags: android, retrofit

I am calling method login but it always returns login failed and mLoggedInUser always null(NullPointerException).

how do I pass response in mLoggedInUser. Please help!!!

```
public class LoginDataSource {

    private LoggedInUser mLoggedInUser;

    public Result<LoggedInUser> login(String username, String password) {

        try {
//            LoggedInUser fakeUser =
//                    new LoggedInUser(
//                            java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
//                            "Jane Doe");
            Call<LoggedInUser> loggedInUserCall = API.getLoginService().login(username, password);
            loggedInUserCall.enqueue(new Callback<LoggedInUser>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<LoggedInUser> call, Response<LoggedInUser> response) {

                    mLoggedInUser = response.body();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<LoggedInUser> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
            if (mLoggedInUser != null)
                return new Result.Success<>(mLoggedInUser);
            return new Result.Error(new Exception("Login Failed"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new Result.Error(new IOException("Error logging in", e));
        }
    }

    public void logout() {
        // TODO: revoke authentication
    }
}
```

Comment: Its an asynchronous call so it will null always cause you  are returning from a method . You have to use a Callback to return login result to caller .

Comment: and how to use callback

Comment: please help me can u correct this code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42636247/how-can-i-return-data-in-method-from-retrofit-onresponse

Answer (score 0):

you should create interface like this :

```
public interface NetworkResponseCallback {
    public void onSuccess(LoggedInUser user);
    public void onFailure(Throwable t);
}
```

then edit your method

```
    public class LoginDataSource {

    //private LoggedInUser mLoggedInUser;

    public void login(String username, String password , 
NetworkResponseCallback callback) {

        try {
//            LoggedInUser fakeUser =
//                    new LoggedInUser(
//                            java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
//                            "Jane Doe");
            Call<LoggedInUser> loggedInUserCall = 
     API.getLoginService().login(username, password);
            loggedInUserCall.enqueue(new Callback<LoggedInUser>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<LoggedInUser> call, 
                                       Response<LoggedInUser> response) {

                    //mLoggedInUser = response.body();
                    if (callback != null)
                        callback.onSuccess(response.body());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<LoggedInUser> call, Throwable t) {
                    callback.onFailure(new Exception("Login Failed"));
                }
            });
//            if (mLoggedInUser != null)
//                return new Result.Success<>(mLoggedInUser);
//            return new Result.Error(new Exception("Login Failed"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new Result.Error(new IOException("Error logging in", e));
        }
    }

    public void logout() {
        // TODO: revoke authentication
    }
}
```

Comment: public Result<LoggedInUser> login(String username, String password){
        // handle login
        Result<LoggedInUser> result = dataSource.login(username, password, mResponseCallback);
        if (result instanceof Result.Success) {
            setLoggedInUser(((Result.Success<LoggedInUser>) result).getData());
        }
        return result;
    }

Comment: how it will return response

Comment: result class is there to hold results