# How to pass the return value to a method and get the response values in java android retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I want to pass this mValue to another method called onPass()

After passing the value I tend to get the response from it since I could not pass the value its not possible for me to print and store the response value. The response fails everytime I pass the Mvalue to the Call.

```
public String getValue(){
        User user = new User(mEmail,mPassword);
        Call<Value> call = xyz.value(user);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Login>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Value> call, Response<Value> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    mValue = response.body().getValue();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"xyz",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Value> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Failed!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        return mValue;
    }

private void onPass() {
        Call<PassData> call1 = xyz.user(mValue);
        call1.enqueue(new Callback<PassData>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PassData> call, Response<PassData> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                   //I want to print the response data from the value passed to the call1
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Unauthenticated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PassData> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Unauthenticated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't return value in Async method. because before you get response from callback, return statement will be invoked. if you do return, always you will get null.so pass result as argument into method.

```
public void getValue(){
        User user = new User(mEmail,mPassword);
        Call<Value> call = xyz.value(user);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Login>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Value> call, Response<Value> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    mValue = response.body().getValue();
                     
                    onPass(mValue);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"xyz",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Value> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Failed!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
      
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried this but when passing the mValue since I am passing it to another callback There's another response value I want to get from the value passed. So it's not working for me.

Comment: Take a look here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34184088/how-can-i-return-value-from-function-onresponse-of-retrofit)@Jack